# How to display a webview in full screen (autofit)

Tags: layout, swift, webview, ios8

I am developing a webview app. 
I need that the webview covers all the content (all the space available!) but I can't get to this...
I've tried several ways but stil don't understand how to tell the webview to autofit depending on the screen.

Here is my situation now: 
[image]

And this if I rotate the device
[image]

I guess this means that I'm not working in the right way, eh ? Can anybody lead me to this right?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this 4 constraint like this for your webView.

[image]